# Is not possible to toggle fullscreen in iframe for flash video?

Tags: iframe, embed

I'm using embed code to do live stream and the embed code like youtube one works perfectly

but some of them I have to use code such as iframe the fullscreen feature doesn't work.

```
<iframe src="linkhere" width="600" height="450"/>
```

and I can not toggle the video into fullscreen

will it be any possible way to make it fullscreen if they click on the option?

or will it be any other embed code that similar to iframe to use?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem could be that the flash plugin recognises iframe as your "fullscreen"..
When looking at the youtube embed code, i recognised a function "allowfullscreen" within the iframe definition
make sure you also have this part in your code..

```
<iframe width="560" height="315" src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/NWHfY_lvKIQ" frameborder="0" **allowfullscreen**></iframe>
```

else there might be another option beside an iframe..

Comment: I'm accepting your question, but that doesn't answer my question ;though this I found the answer myself that it can't be done if the video format I use was something else like say for example: .m3u